# Generate and estimate models like IGARCH, FIGARCH or HYGARCH

Tags: python, r, simulation, modeling, arch

my issue is that I'm trying to simulate modifications of GARCH model like **IGARCH, FIGARCH or HYGARCH**.
I have already found that some of them is possible to generate in R (*rugarch* or (no more existing) *fSeries* package) or in Python (*arch* library). I will organize my questions into the following points:

**1. How can I simulate an IGARCH model in Python?**

I tried these two ways:

1) used *GARCH.simulate* with fixed parameters where alfas and betas sum to 1. But there was an error 
      message about non-stationarity and it took intercept in order to initialize the model. And I'm not 
      sure if it is OK and the simulated series is still IGARCH (in my opinion it is only moved by 
      constant so it should have had no crucial effect). 
      I have also programmed my own function for GARCH simulation, and it works also for coefficients 
      that sum to 1. Hopefully, the implementation is good...The only restriction for IGARCH that 
      differentiates it from GARCH is that the sum of coefficients equals 1, right?.

2) used *FIGARCH.simulate* with fixed parameters where d=1 which is a special case of FIGARCH models 
      which in that case become IGARCH(p,q) models. But the error there was *invalid value encountered in 
      sqrt: data[t] = errors[t] * np.sqrt(sigma2[t])*.

**2. Is there any free software in which the HYGARCH is implemented? If not, could somebody advise me how 
         to implement that model in R or Python?**

The model is already implemented in Ox Metrics 8, but it is a paid software. I found that the 
   interface to these Ox Metrics functions were implemented in the R package *fSeries* which, however 
   doesn't exist anymore and I'm not able to install the older version on my R version 3.5.1. And in 
   Python there is no such a model implemented.

**3. Corresponds model specification "fgarch" in the function *ugarchspec(...)* of *rugarch* package in R to the FIGARCH model? If not, is FIGARCH implemented in the R software?**
     My R Code is:

```
 spec=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="fGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1), submodel="GARCH"),
            mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), include.mean=TRUE), distribution.model="std",
            fixed.pars=list(mu=0.001,omega=0.00001, alpha1=0.05,beta1=0.90,delta = 0.00001,
                            shape=4))
```

I found somewhere on the Internet that there is also possible to specify "figarch" in upper function instead of "fgarch", but in that case I'm not able to simulate the path by using *ugarchpath(...)*.

Thank you in advance! I need this for my master thesis so I appreciate any recommendations, advises etc.

Domca

Comment: I think you should reconsider posting this question on Cross Validated as it is focused more on statistics as on programming. There, you may get better responses.

Comment: Nevertheless, according to documentation, the FIGARCH models are implemented in the `R rugarch` library: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf

Comment: @tmfmnk thank you, I'll try it. To the *rugarch* package, yes, this I've read also but I don't know, how to implement it with the functions *ugarchspec(...)* while when I specify as an argument  *model="fiGARCH"* I can't  use *ugarchpath(...)* to simulate series and plot them and I don't know, what I am doing wrong...I obtain **Error - $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**.